# Cannot construct a collection of type ...Inclusive[Long] with elements of type Long based on a collection of type ...Inclusive[Long]

Tags: scala, scala-collections, typechecking

I'm not sure I understand why the following happens.

## Compiles and works:

**With `Int`s without converting to a `List`**

```
import scala.util.Random
val xs = 1 to 10
Random.shuffle(xs)
```

**With `Long`s after converting to a `List`**

```
import scala.util.Random
val xs = 1L to 10L
Random.shuffle(xs.toList) //<-- I had to materialize it to a list
```

## Doesn't compile

**With `Long`s *without* converting to a `List`**

```
val xs = 1L to 10L
Random.shuffle(xs)
```

This one throws this exception:

```
Error: Cannot construct a collection of type 
scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Long] with elements of type 
Long based on a collection of type 
scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[Long].
  Random.shuffle(xs)
                ^
```

I'm curious why? Is that because there is a missing CanBuildFrom or something like that? Is there a good reason why there isn't one?

(scala version 2.11.5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of both `CanBuildFrom`(1) and type inference mechanism(2).

1) You may find that `genericBuilder` of `Range`/`NumericRange` (same for `Inclusive`) is:

```
 genericBuilder[B]: Builder[B, IndexedSeq[B]]
```

So there is only `CanBuildFrom[Range, B, IndexedSeq]`, which uses this builder. The reason why is simple, you may find it in builder's description:

> A builder lets one construct a collection incrementally, by adding elements to the builder with += and then converting to the required collection type with result.

You just can't construct inclusive range incrementally, as it won't be a range anymore then (but still be an `IndexedSeq`); however, you can do such constructions with `Seq`.

Just to demonstrate the difference between `IndexedSeq` and `Inclusive`

```
scala> (1 to 5)
res14: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> (1 to 5) ++ (7 to 10) //builder used here
res15: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

This means that you can't "build" any range, regardless `Int` (`Range`) or `Long` (`Numeric`) and you should always pass `IndexedSeq` as `To` parameter of the builder. However, `IndexedSeq` is automatically specified for `Int` (`Range`), when you pass it to the `shuffle` function.

2) It's not working for [`NumericRange.Inclusive[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.NumericRange$$Inclusive) because it's a polymorphic type (generic). While, regular [`Range.Inclusive`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range$$Inclusive) (not generic) explicitly extends `IndexedSeq[Int]`. Looking on shuffle signature:

```
shuffle[T, CC[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](xs: CC[T])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[CC[T], T, CC[T]]): CC[T]
```

Higher-order type `CC` is becoming `NumericRange.Inclusive` here as it's the biggest parametrized type inherited by `NumericRange.Inclusive`. In case of `Range.Inclusive`, that was an `IndexedSeq` (as smaller `Range.Inclusive` is not generic). So `Range.Inclusive` just got lucky to be not affected by (1).

Finally, this will work:

```
scala> Random.shuffle[Long, IndexedSeq](xs)
res8: IndexedSeq[Long] = Vector(9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 2, 5, 4, 10, 1)

scala> Random.shuffle(xs: IndexedSeq[Long])
res11: IndexedSeq[Long] = Vector(6, 9, 7, 3, 1, 8, 5, 10, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! great answer. one quick question - which books / training / do you recommend to get to the same level of understanding you have? :) I mean unless you are a typesafe / EPFL employee, even experienced Scala developers I know don't understand the type system into that level of detail (and most books don't go down to that level either). What's your secret source to becoming a Scala guru? :D

Comment: Oh! I'd say. I left my job in Ukraine and moved to the Thailand for few months. Beer, palms and cute asian girls. So, I started to play with stackoverflow just to not forget the Scala and to eventually find some new job in EU/US. Sun, girls and stackoverflow - that's it ;)